# Odin 6.0 not booting on Intel Tiger Lake laptop

Tags: laptop

I just got a new Intel Tiger Lake laptop with the 1135G7 cpu and the latest Odin ISO does not boot - it appears to go to black screen with non responsive keyboard - cannot switch to TTY etc.

Tried some kernel boot parameters like nomodeset, i915.modeset=0 which dont seem to help.

Now, the latest current ISO has kernel 5.8 which is supposed to work - indeed Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4 and ubuntu 20.10 with kernel 5.8 work well - heck even Hera boots.

Any pointers to get it to work?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the place for beta versions of eOS. You want: https://github.com/elementary/

Comment: I've posted here too -> https://github.com/elementary/os/discussions/455

Comment: Thanks for helping to make eOS better!